# Bootstrap 4 - Column Form Label with max width

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, dynamic-columns

I'm building a form in a full-width fluid layout with 2 columns, the label column and the inputs column.

the problem is because it is a fluid layout with wide screens a col-2 label is too big and col-1 is too small.

is there a way to give a max width to the col-form-label column or do i need to create some custom CSS for this columns?

simple demo : https://codepen.io/seltix/pen/aWgVjR

```
<div class="formcontainer">
  
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label class="col-12 col-lg-2 col-form-label">Label</label>
    <div class="col-12 col-lg-10">
      <input class="form-control" type="text" value="">
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label class="col-12 col-lg-2 col-form-label">Longer label</label>
    <div class="col-12 col-lg-10">
      <input class="form-control" type="text" value="">
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label class="col-12 col-lg-2 col-form-label">Longer label (extra)</label>
    <div class="col-12 col-lg-10">
      <input class="form-control" type="text" value="">
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

bootstrap 4 form source: https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/forms/#textual-inputs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The max-width of `col-lg-2` in bootstrap 4 is `16.6667%`, and the screen size boundary is `min-width: 992px`. What you want to do is override the maximum width of those columns in that view using your custom class like this:

**CSS**

```
/* Not too wide */
    @media(min-width: 992px) {
      .col-percent-13 {
           max-width: 13% !important;
      }
    }

/* A little bit narrower */
    @media(min-width: 992px) {
          .col-percent-11 {
               max-width: 11% !important;
          }
        }
```

**Example HTML**

```
<!-- I want all the labels in this form to have a width of 13% -->
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label class="col-12 col-lg-2 col-form-label col-percent-13">Label</label>
    <div class="col-12 col-lg-10">
      <input class="form-control" type="text" value="">
    </div>
```

```
<!-- In another form, I want all the labels to be 11% wide -->
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label class="col-12 col-lg-2 col-form-label col-percent-11">Label</label>
    <div class="col-12 col-lg-10">
      <input class="form-control" type="text" value="">
    </div>
```

Modify the width values and class names to your preference.

Comment: Hi,Ty for rhe reply.  So, with this option I will need to create another set of col because I will need to change the max width of the next columns

Comment: You have more than one form? So define your own widths and apply them to the forms depending on your needs. I have updated my answer to show examples.

Comment: Hi. I do have more than one form but I wasn't talking about that, what I was trying to say is, since the form has 2 columns, if I customize the first column (col-form-label col-lg-2) with a diferente width I will need to customize the second column too (col-lg-10). At the end I will need to generate new col-lg-X classes to apply at this forms right ? :)